# Can you require multiple packages on the same line?

Tags: ruby, require

I have this in my code:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'csv'
```

Which isn't super compact or DRY. Can you put multiple `require`'s on the same line?

Something like this:

```
require 'uri', 'net/http', 'csv'
```

Comment: I would argue that the original is a) what every ruby developer would expect to see; b) definitely DRY. `require` is a method call to `Kernel`. In this instance you are calling the method 3 times with different arguments. Would you consider `1 + 1; 1 + 2; 1 + 3` not DRY because of the repeated integer 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so. Reading the [Kernel#require](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/require) it only accepts one filename as argument.

But you can do something like (don't know if this will feel you better).

```rb
%w[uri net/http csv].each { |f| require f }
```

It's common to perform a runtime require for relative paths like reading files from folder for example.

Comment: Or, if you're a fan of point-free style `%w[uri net/http csv].each(&method(:require))`

Answer (score 1):

> Can you put multiple `require`'s on the same line?

Yes, you can. In fact, the answer to the question "Can you do X in one line" is *always* "Yes", since newlines are *never* needed in Ruby.

```ruby
require 'uri'; require 'net/http'; require 'csv'
```